# Running stand-alone Rails script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, issue-tracking, jsonapi-resources

I'm submitting a bug report to [`jsonapi-resources`](https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources/). Their issue template asks that I create a MCVE using their [template](https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources/blob/master/lib/bug_report_templates/rails_5_master.rb). This looks like a self-contained script for a rails-based project. I've only ever run similar code as an actual rails project with separate files and using `rails server`. My question is, how do I run this self-contained script?

Answer (score 1):

I ran it with

```
ruby <filename>
```

It seems to programmatically install gems.

Comment: This is correct. ActiveRecord and PaperTrail have similar bug report templates, using  `bundler/inline` (pretty cool huh?) and this is the correct way to run them.